# ¿Como puedo enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp a un contacto especifico desde otra aplicación android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que envié un mensaje a un contacto especifico de WhatsApp desde mi app.

Ya intente este codigo.

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:+999999999");
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The text goes here");
mIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

El contacto si se selecciona, pero el problema es que el texto no es recibido por WhatsApp, solo se selecciona el contacto.

ya use este código, y si envira el texto pero tengo que seleccionar manualmente el contacto para que funcione

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: por cuestiones de seguridad, no se permite realizar el preseleccionado del usuario a enviar mensaje, desde una app android, ve mi respuesta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Por cuestiones de seguridad, NO se permite preseleccionar el usuario y enviar el mensaje directamente, si deseas enviar un mensaje Whatsapp desde una aplicación Android.

Así que lo único posible es lo que comentas, se abre la aplicación y el cliente debe seleccionar el usuario que desea enviar el mensaje:

```
public void enviaMensajeWhatsApp(String msj) {    
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");             
            PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msj);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con:"));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp no esta instalado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Ejecutando el método anterior:

```
enviaMensajeWhatsApp("Mi mensaje es abcdef 1234567890");
```

abre la aplicación WhatsApp y tenemos que seleccionar el usuario a enviar el mensaje:

[image: Whatsapp Bosca]

---

### Si deseas pre-seleccionar un usuario para enviar un mensaje, lo puedes realizar mediante un `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, pero requieres que el número definido del contacto debe estar registrado en tu teléfono.

El número debe contener el [código del país](https://countrycode.org/) y el código de área , iniciando con el signo "+" , por ejemplo mi país México `+52`, código de área para `Mexico City` `55`  y mi telefono `1234567890`:

```
 String msj = "Mi mensaje es abcdef 1234567890";
 String numeroTel = "+52551234567890";
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 String uri = "whatsapp://send?phone=" + numeroTel + "&text=" + msj;
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

De esta forma se abrirá la ventana del contacto a enviar y el mensaje automáticamente, en este caso también por seguridad un usuario humano tiene que activar el envió:

[image: Whatsapp Jorgesys]

Comment: Si, asi lo tendre que usar. Gracias

Comment: hay algún código para que el mensaje sea enviado, es decir que no solo aparezca en el editor sino que sea enviado de una vez (darle enviar desde la App de tercero)???

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que mi respuesta llega unos años tarde pero encontre ésta solución que a mi en lo personal me sirvió y la comparto a continuación:

```
String numeroTelefono = "591..."; // Aquí va el número de teléfono, no olvidar el código de pais al inicio
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(numeroTelefono) + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Prueba de mensaje");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Para whatsapp business cambiar:

```
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
```

Por:

```
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp.w4b", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
```

Y finalmente si a alguien le sirve, para enviar una imagen seria de la siguiente forma:

```
String numeroTelefono = "591..."; // Aquí va el número de teléfono, no olvidar el código de pais al inicio
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File file = new File("path de la imagen");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
sendIntent.setType("image");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(numeroTelefono) + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Prueba de texto e imagen");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Ésta es la única forma que me sirvió por el momento para abrir whatsapp con un contacto en especifico. Saludos ;)

Comment: Hola, me gusta la respuesta, imagino que solo lo selecciona pero no lo envia verdad?

Comment: Si no la envía pero al menos abre el contacto

Comment: Eso es excelente, ya veo la clase ContactPicker.

Comment: Israel-ICM buenas tardes, una inquietud, ¿hay forma de colocar un emoticon? como pulgar arriba o carrita feliz. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @Isabel, bueno la verdad no intente enviar emoticonos pero lo que posiblemente te funcione es abrir whatsapp web y copiar el emoticono que necesitas y pegarlo como texto en la variable del mensaje "☺️..." imagino que funcionaria.

Answer (score 2):

Modifica tu Intent para que quede así, en este caso lo tengo una función en donde la llamo desde un botón por rapidez, pero igual lo modificas a tus necesidades.

```
prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickWhatsApp();
        }
    });


public void onClickWhatsApp() {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "Tu texto aquí";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con"));

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp no está instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
```

[image: imagen]

fuente -> [aquí](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Comment: Hola me parece interesante el uso de <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a> desde una página web abrir la app, claro necesitamos permisos, muy buen aporte! +1