# Enviar un mensaje vía whatsapp, Android Studio

Tags: android, whatsapp

Buenas tardes; alguien sabe como se puede hacer, quisiera poner un botón en mi proyecto Android Studio desde el cual se abra la aplicación de whatsapp para envíar un mensaje a determinado número, si el numero no está guardado que antes pida guardarlo en la agenda. Por favor.

Comment: tienes algún código de ejemplo? sería más fácil ayudarte así.

Comment: No tengo un código ejemplo hasta ahora estoy buscando como hacerlo, encontré   https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6690/95

Comment: @Alfredo puedes realizar una búsqueda en el sitio, posiblemente lo que preguntas alguien más lo pregunto, saludos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea/Ocupa Intent para compartir información de tu app a whatsapp

Ejemplo:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Hay que indicar a que aplicación hay que compartir esa información

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

La ultima linea de codigo va antes de que inicies la nueva actividad/Activity.

Comment: Esta solución permite compartir usando whatsapp pero no permite seleccionar el destinatario de antemano de la lista de contactos. De hecho esa funcionalidad Whatsapp no la permite.

Comment: esta respuesta es solo compartir, ya existen varías preguntas en el sitio : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a