# Abrir Whatsapp desde un botón en android

Tags: android, whatsapp

Intento con este código pero me abre los contactos que están registrados en WhatsApp para enviar un mensaje y no es lo que deseo y lo que  busco es abrir
la pagina principal de WhatsApp

```
 public void whatsap(View view) {
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hola");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir con:"));
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp no esta instalado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }


}
```

}

intente con este pero me tira error

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("com.whatsapp" ));
    startActivity(i);

    try{
        startActivity(i);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "No encontramos la aplicación en tu dispositivo inténtalo luego.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente, No necesitas definir:

```
PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

para definir que la aplicación Whatsapp será la que recibirá los datos simplemente se usa:

```
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

tampoco es necesario:

```
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir con:"));
```

Con respecto a tu comentario:

> Intento con este código pero me abre los contactos que están
>   registrados en WhatsApp para enviar un mensaje y no es lo que deseo y
>   lo que busco es abrir

En realidad Whatsapp no envía directamente a un usuario el mensaje, por seguridad la api no permite enviar un mensaje a un usuario especifico, revisa esta pregunta:

**[¿Como puedo enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp a un contacto especifico desde otra aplicación android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a)**

---

Esta sería la forma adecuada, usando `Intent.ACTION_SEND`:

#### Enviar mensaje por Whatsapp.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hola sasuke uchia.");
 try{
     startActivity(intent);
 }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La aplicación Whastapp no se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```