# Problemas con Intent.SetPackage("com.whatsapp")

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

estoy haciendo una mini app de prueba que comparte una cadena de texto, y quería que lo haga directamente por whatsapp, salteando el paso de que despliegue la eleccion de app por la cual compartir.

Encontre que al intent se le podía hacer un `intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")` para que lo haga directamente luego del startActivity, pero no lo hace, y hasta crashea. Si le saco esa linea funciona perfectamente, mostrandome las apps para elegir por cual compartir.

Alguno sabe por qué?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String textoUwu = "uwu";
    Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,textoUwu);
    try{
        startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Whastapp No Instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

Mi Logcat dice lo siguiente:

> 2018-10-25 10:48:00.459 19754-19754/com.example.ciro.uwuapp.app
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ciro.uwuapp.app, PID: 19754
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x1
>   pkg=com.whatsapp clip={text/plain T:uwu} (has extras) }
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1944)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4501)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4459)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4820)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4788)
>           at com.example.ciro.uwuapp.feature.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: definir ".setPackage("com.whatsapp")" es importante ya que determina que usaras Whatsapp para enviar el texto. ¿Que se muestra en el LogCat, si desarrollas para android, es esencial el uso del LogCat para poder solucionar problemas en la aplicación. Te podría asegurar que el problema se encuentra en otro punto del código.

Comment: Como mandas llamar el método onClick? tu código es correcto , revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a

Comment: Hola. Mi Logcat dice lo siguiente:

Comment: gracias por agregar la información, sabes me gustaría saber si ¿tienes en verdad instalado Whatsapp? @Ciro

Answer (score 0):

Al producirse el error

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

especificado en tu LogCat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.ciro.uwuapp.app, PID: 19754
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x1
>   pkg=com.whatsapp clip={text/plain T:uwu} (has extras) }

indica que el sistema operativo no encontró ninguna actividad que pueda manejar este intent, ACTION_SEND. Para esto precisamente se usa en el código  try / catch, ya que no puede estar seguro de que exista una actividad que pueda manejar su intent.

Debes asegurarte de agregar el catch para "atrapar" este tipo de error y mostrar el toast con el mensaje que indica que Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado en el dispositivo

```
  try{
        startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Whastapp No Instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. EN el codigo del inicio esta envuelto en un Try Catch. Y siempre me entra al ciclo del catch. Nunca me ejecuta whatsapp de una, como si no encontrara dicho package ("com.whatsapp")

Comment: Si no encuentra el paquete com.whatsapp al menos debe mostrar el Toast ya que estas capturando el error que se muestra en el LogCat : "ActivityNotFoundException"  , recuerda que en Java es try catch y no Try Catch .

Comment: Si, lo muestra el Toast. Entra sin problemas al ciclo del catch. Pero no entiendo por qué entra al catch si todo lo anterior se supone que esta bien. El texto del logcat que puse previamente es si saco el try catch. Tal vez hace falta importar algo mas para que tome el setPackage("com.whatsapp") y yo no lo estoy haciendo.

Comment: Ciro, verificaste que tienes instalado Whatsapp y funciona sin problema @CiroGonzalez

Comment: Si, es mi celular de uso diario en el que lo pruebo. Android stock 8.1. No se si me faltaran permisos en el manifest o importar alguna libreria

Comment: Oh esta información es importante, estas usando sistema operativo 8.1 @CiroGonzalez no tengo un dispositivo con esta versión pero permiteme investigar si encuentro información relacionada a esto.