# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp a un contacto específico desde otra aplicación android? Desde 0

Tags: java, android-studio, whatsapp, mensajes

He formulado esta pregunta de nuevo, ya que, la he visto en otros ítem, pero no sé como aplicarlo en mi proyecto.¿qué pasos debo seguir para aplicar este código? hasta aqui voy:

```
Button btn_ws1;


protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_items_orders);
    btn_ws1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ws);

    btn_ws1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsmto:" + "+584127608991");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(i);
        }



    });
```

todo este codigo esta dentro de un

```
public class ws_send extends AppCompatActivity {...}
```

Comment: Ese código es de esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a a que te refieres con mensaje_ws ???

Comment: el mensaje_ws es el nombre que le di a mi layout

Comment: es el que cargas en tu activity mediante setContentView () ?

Comment: si, es algo que se ve sencillo, pero ando parado por eso

Comment: agrega ese layout a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: y el codigo de tu activity para comentar donde agregar lo demas

Comment: copio y pego y me sale errores en todo el codigo y no me deja guardar

Comment: Existe otro medio xdonde enviarlo?

Comment: ya modifique y este es los que llevo hasta ahora, compila la app, pero toco el boton y no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

Para llamarlo desde un botón, obten su referencia mediante `findViewById()` ( suponiendo que estas en `onCreate()` de tu `Activity` ) y posteriormente llamas el método dentro del clickListener:

```
//Obtiene referencia del botón.
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_ws);

//Configura listener a button y llama método.
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enviaMensajeWhatsApp("Soy Jeckson y este es mi mensaje");
        }
    });
```

[¿Como puedo enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp a un contacto especifico desde otra aplicación android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6683/como-puedo-enviar-un-mensaje-por-whatsapp-a-un-contacto-especifico-desde-otra-a)

---

De acuerdo a tu código serìa:

```
public class ws_send extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_items_orders);
    btn_ws1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ws);

    btn_ws1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

        //Llama mètodo:
        enviaMensajeWhatsApp("Soy Jeckson y este es mi mensaje");    

        }
      });

    }


public void enviaMensajeWhatsApp(String msj) {    
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");             
        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msj);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Compartir con:"));
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp no esta instalado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
      }
  }


}
```

Comment: ok ok entiendo, como hiciera para pasarte el codigo de mi activity, y puedieras ayudarme en donde deberia colocar eso que me dices

Comment: Button btn_ws1;


    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row_items_orders);
        btn_ws1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ws);

        btn_ws1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsmto:" + "+584127608991");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(i);
            }

Comment: Ok revisa la actualizaciòn , esa es la forma de como enviar el mensaje via Whatsapp. es importante que sepas que la API no puede enviar automaticamente el mensaje a un usuario especifico, asi que debes seleccionarlo.

Comment: Sera, intentare ver como actualizarlo, el codigo que ingrese compila todo fino, pero al presionar boton no pasa nada :(

Comment: es posible modificar este codigo para en vez de abrir WS, abra un enlace de una pagina web?

Comment: Si no sucede nada debes revisar el LogCat, debes tener instalada la aplicaciòn Whatsapp. Si deseas realizar otra pregunta puedes agregarla en el sitio para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, la hare :D